# Why can't I get a Byte[] from this DataRow?

Tags: c#, sqlite, api

I'm trying to get a `byte[]` from blob stored in SQLite, but the byte[] length is always 1

```
       foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {

                    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])row["password_value"];

            }
```

This the Wrapper Class I used, I suppose the problem in the wrapper I tested the code using normal  SQLite wrapper it works fine,  but I could not figure out what's the problem with wrapper

```
public class SQLiteBase
    {
        // imports system functions for work with pointers
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private extern static IntPtr HeapAlloc(IntPtr heap, UInt32 flags, UInt32 bytes);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private extern static IntPtr GetProcessHeap();

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private extern static int lstrlen(IntPtr str);

        // imports  SQLite functions
        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_open(IntPtr fileName, out IntPtr database);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_close(IntPtr database);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_exec(IntPtr database, IntPtr query, IntPtr callback, IntPtr arguments,
            out IntPtr error);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern IntPtr sqlite3_errmsg(IntPtr database);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_prepare_v2(IntPtr database, IntPtr query, int length, out IntPtr statement,
            out IntPtr tail);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_step(IntPtr statement);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_column_count(IntPtr statement);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern IntPtr sqlite3_column_name(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_column_type(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_column_int(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern double sqlite3_column_double(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern IntPtr sqlite3_column_text(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern IntPtr sqlite3_column_blob(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern IntPtr sqlite3_column_table_name(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_finalize(IntPtr handle);

        // SQLite constants 
        private const int SQL_OK = 0;

        private const int SQL_ROW = 100;
        private const int SQL_DONE = 101;

        /// <summary>
        /// SQLite data types.
        ///  </summary>
        public enum SQLiteDataTypes
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Integer numbers.
            /// </summary>
            INT = 1,

            ///  <summary>
            /// Decimal numbers.
            ///  </summary>
            FLOAT,

            ///  <summary>
            /// All kinds of texts.
            /// </summary>
            TEXT,

            ///  <summary>
            /// Blob objects - binary large objects.
            /// </summary>
            BLOB,

            ///  <summary>
            /// Nothing.
            ///  </summary>
            NULL
        };

        //  pointer to database
        private IntPtr database;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates new instance of SQLiteBase  class with no database attached.
        /// </summary>
        public SQLiteBase()
        {
            database = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates new instance of SQLiteBase class and opens database with  given name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param  name="baseName">Name (and path) to SQLite database file</param>
        public SQLiteBase(String baseName)
        {
            OpenDatabase(baseName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens database. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseName">Name of database file</param>
        public void OpenDatabase(String baseName)
        {
            // opens database 
            if (sqlite3_open(StringToPointer(baseName), out database) != SQL_OK)
            {
                // if there is some error, database  pointer is set to 0 and exception is throws
                database = IntPtr.Zero;
                throw new Exception("Error with opening  database " + baseName + "!");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes opened database.
        /// </summary>
        public void CloseDatabase()
        {
            // closes the database if there is one opened
            if (database != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                sqlite3_close(database);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the list of tables in opened  database.
        /// </summary>
        ///  <returns></returns>
        public ArrayList GetTables()
        {
            // executes query that select names of all  tables and views in master table of every database
            String query = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " +
                           "WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE  'sqlite_%'" +
                           "UNION ALL " +
                           "SELECT name FROM  sqlite_temp_master " +
                           "WHERE  type IN ('table','view') " +
                           "ORDER BY 1";
            DataTable table = ExecuteQuery(query);

            // when table is generater, it writes all table names in list  that is returned
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            }
            return list;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes query that does not return anything (e.g. UPDATE,  INSERT, DELETE).
        /// </summary>
        ///  <param name="query"></param>
        public void ExecuteNonQuery(String query)
        {
            // calles  SQLite function that executes non-query
            IntPtr error;
            sqlite3_exec(database, StringToPointer(query), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out error);
            // if there is error, excetion  is thrown
            if (error != IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Exception("Error with executing non-query: \"" + query + "\"!\n" +
                                    PointerToString(sqlite3_errmsg(error)));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes query that does  return something (e.g. SELECT).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query"></param>
        ///  <returns></returns>
        public DataTable ExecuteQuery(String query)
        {
            // processed  query
            IntPtr statement;

            // excess  data, it has no use
            IntPtr excessData;

            // process query and make statement
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, StringToPointer(query), GetPointerLenght(StringToPointer(query)),
                out statement, out excessData);

            // table for result of function
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // reads  first row - it is different from next rows because it also creates table  columns
            // result - returns SLQ_ROW while there is next  row
            int result = ReadFirstRow(statement, ref table);

            // reads rows
            while (result == SQL_ROW)
            {
                result = ReadNextRow(statement, ref table);
            }

            // finalize executing this  query
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

            //  returns table
            return table;
        }

        // private function for reading firs row and creating DataTable
        private int ReadFirstRow(IntPtr statement, ref DataTable table)
        {
            // create new instance of DataTable with name  "resultTable"
            table = new DataTable("resultTable");

            // evaluates statement 
            int resultType = sqlite3_step(statement);

            // if result of statement is  SQL_ROW, create new table and write row in it
            if (resultType == SQL_ROW)
            {
                // returns  number of columns returned by statement
                int columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

                //  declartaion of variables for reading first row
                String columnName = "";
                int columnType = 0;
                object[] columnValues = new object[columnCount];

                // reads columns one by one
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    //  returns the name of current column
                    columnName = PointerToString(sqlite3_column_name(statement, i));

                    // returns the type of current column
                    columnType = sqlite3_column_type(statement, i);

                    // checks type of columns - neccessary because different functions  are required for different types
                    switch (columnType)
                    {
                        // in  case of integer column
                        case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.INT:
                        {
                            // adds new integer column to table
                            table.Columns.Add(columnName, Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

                            //  writes column value in object array
                            columnValues[i] = sqlite3_column_int(statement, i);
                            break;
                        }
                        // same as for integer, this one is for float
                        case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.FLOAT:
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(columnName, Type.GetType("System.Single"));
                            columnValues[i] = sqlite3_column_double(statement, i);
                            break;
                        }
                        // ... for text
                        case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.TEXT:
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(columnName, Type.GetType("System.String"));
                            columnValues[i] = PointerToString(sqlite3_column_text(statement, i));
                            break;
                        }
                        // ... for blob - blob are written in table as  strings!!
                        case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.BLOB:
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(columnName, Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
                            columnValues[i] = PointerToByte(sqlite3_column_blob(statement, i));
                            break;
                        }
                        // in case of something other, value is read as string
                        default:
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(columnName, Type.GetType("System.String"));
                            columnValues[i] = "";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // writes column values to table
                table.Rows.Add(columnValues);
            }

            //  evalute statemnet for next results
            return sqlite3_step(statement);
        }

        // private function  for reading rows other than first
        // it' same like first  row, only without creating table and columns
        private int ReadNextRow(IntPtr statement, ref DataTable table)
        {
            int columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

            int columnType = 0;
            object[] columnValues = new object[columnCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                columnType = sqlite3_column_type(statement, i);

                switch (columnType)
                {
                    case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.INT:
                    {
                        columnValues[i] = sqlite3_column_int(statement, i);
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.FLOAT:
                    {
                        columnValues[i] = sqlite3_column_double(statement, i);
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.TEXT:
                    {
                        columnValues[i] = PointerToString(sqlite3_column_text(statement, i));
                        break;
                    }
                    case (int) SQLiteDataTypes.BLOB:
                    {
                        columnValues[i] = PointerToByte(sqlite3_column_blob(statement, i));
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        columnValues[i] = "";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(columnValues);
            return sqlite3_step(statement);
        }

        // converts string  to pointer
        private IntPtr StringToPointer(String str)
        {
            // if string is null, pointer is 0
            if (str == null)
            {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            else
            {
                //  else, convert it to pointer
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(str);
                int length = bytes.Length + 1;
                IntPtr pointer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (UInt32) length);
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pointer, bytes.Length);
                Marshal.WriteByte(pointer, bytes.Length, 0);
                return pointer;
            }
        }

        // convert pointer  to string
        private String PointerToString(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;

            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            int length = GetPointerLenght(ptr);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[length];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, length);
            return encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        private Byte[] PointerToByte(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;


            int length = GetPointerLenght(ptr);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[length];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, length);
            return bytes;
        }

        // returns length of pointer
        private int GetPointerLenght(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
                return 0;
            return lstrlen(ptr);
        }
    }
```

, I think the problem is in this section, or not

```
 private Byte[] PointerToByte(IntPtr ptr)
 {
    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        return null;


    int length = GetPointerLenght(ptr);
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, length);
    return bytes;
}
```

***UPDATE***

```
private int GetPointerLenght(IntPtr ptr)
{
    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        return 0;
    return lstrlen(ptr); // here the problem this gets the length of string and im passing an array of bytes  
}
```

so the question now how to get the length of the byte array from pointer ?

Comment: What is this 'normal sqlite wrapper' you speak of?  The standard NET DBProvider offers all the functionality needed to read and write `byte[]`...and it supports a great many more other data types than you have there

Comment: im  talking about the one you get from nuget packages ,but  my problem with  it it size 300kb,and 1.4M  for interpol file

Comment: You have to know the length of the byte array first. From documentation "If the result is a BLOB or a TEXT string, then the sqlite3_column_bytes() or sqlite3_column_bytes16() interfaces can be used to determine the size of that BLOB or string."

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @FCin pointing out

> sqlite3_column_bytes() or sqlite3_column_bytes16()

here the solution get the size or byte[] array from unmanaged code

```
        [DllImport("sqlite3")]
        private static extern int sqlite3_column_bytes(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);
        private int getSizeOfBytes(IntPtr statement,int i)
        {
           return sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, i);
        }
```

ANd you pass it like that

```
columnValues[i] = PointerToByte(sqlite3_column_blob(statement, i), getSizeOfBytes(statement,i));
```